# Find out number of people who are at the office at 6 p.m

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a simple query to which I forgot the solution, I remember there was a function to look for each possible value in a range, so I am asking this query here.

There is a table 'Time' with 2 columns checkInTime and CheckOutTime of the employees for one day in the office.

in the format: hour*100+minutes

For instance:

| Check in | Check out |
| --- | --- |
| 850 | 1758 |
| 902 | 1640 |
| 1330 | 1530 |
| 1630 | 2020 |

Find out the  number of people which were in office at 6 pm (1800)

To this I came with this query (obviously its wrong since I dont know how to look for the value 1800 in the checkin-checkout range):

select sum(rn)
from Table
row_number() over() as rn
Where Checkout >= 1800

Comment: 1) You don't need SUM(), because you're not adding anything. You're trying to COUNT() them. 2) You don't need the *row_number() over() as m* for a simple SELECT statement at all - there's no need for any windowing functions here. 3) Find a book or tutorial on SQL, so you learn the basics (which is all you need for this query). Until you learn the basics of the language, you're going to keep struggling to complete even the simplest tasks (like this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table 
    WHERE 1800 BETWEEN CheckIn AND CheckOut)
```

That said this is incomplete without a full date to qualify that they were not in longer than a day.